# How do I use Gibbed Save Editor to flag a mission as complete?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the beginning of ME3 I completed the Grissom Academy quest but after I accidentally loaded a save from before the mission and continued from there. I only just realized this +20 hours later and I'm almost done with the game, so there's no way I'm going to load the correct (and now very old) save.

Is there any way to flag this mission as complete in my current save so I can get the war assets, etc? I'm new to Gibbed Save Editor. I know the quest ID number but I don't know where or how to edit its progress. If this is possible, can someone give me instructions?

Edit: I do have coalesced